# 'AngularJS' with 'MVC5' landing page when multiple users

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs with MVC5 (.net) for creating single page website. I have problem setting default landing page of site.

Site has two types of users; one is admin and the other one is the client.

When "client User" logs into site then page redirect user at following location:

```
.when('/dash_dailyStatus', { templateUrl: './Dashboard/Userdashboard', controller: 'UserDashboardController' })
```

And if "Admin" logs into site then page redirects the user to the following location:

```
.when('/dash', { templateUrl: './Dashboard/Admindashboard', controller: 'AdminDashboardController' })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.otherwise({redirectTo: '/defaultpage'})` to set up a default redirect for everything that doesn't match your routes. But I am not sure if I understand your question.

Will update my answer if you provide additional info :)